# Spring mvc delete in cascade doesnt work?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm currently building a prototype for a school project. I implemented a simple delete button for a "ride" but if the ride has a comment or a vote attached to it, it will give me java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`niftyrailway`.`vote`, CONSTRAINT `FKqsvgyxwc88ggq58ltbl7kgq8e` FOREIGN KEY (`ride_id`) REFERENCES `ride` (`id`)).
What can I do ?

Here is my code https://github.com/CatalinBratu7/NiftyRailway

Comment: Relevant code needs to be posted in the question, not as a link. This both makes the content searchable and ensures that it will not go stale.

Comment: Perhaps adding `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your database where the FK is located. Otherwise, if you delete all the `comments` associated with the `ride` first that will work as there will be no constraints anymore, however, that is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Your Ride object has not the references of vote and comment so you can't add desired cascading behaviour. first delete all votes and comments of the ride programmatically and then delete the ride.